# javascript display seconds in countdown

Tags: javascript

I 'm having a modal window which pops up and lets the user know that his session is about to expire in N seconds. What I'd like to do is to display the remaining time to the user, so the message will be something like

```
"Your session is about to expire in 2 minutes" // if remaining time is more than 1 minute, then display it in minutes else in seconds - if possible
...
"Your session is about to expire in 50 seconds"
...
"Your session is about to expire in 15 seconds"
...
```

This is my code

```
<div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <h2>Session timeout</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Your session is about to expire in <span id="time-remain"></span> and you will be logged out.</p>
            <p><button class="btn blue" id="extend-session">Extend Session</button></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

This is the javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById('session-timeout');
    var timeCount = document.getElementById('time-remain');
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var extendSession = document.getElementById("extend-session"); // Get the extend button
    var sessionTimeout = <?php echo config_item('session-timeout'); ?>; // set timeout - temporarily set to 4 mins ( i.e. 240000 ms)

var interval;

function countDown(time) {

    var unit = 'seconds';

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (time <= 0) {

            // logout when session expires
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('Logout!');
                // window.location = "<?php echo admin_url('auth/logout'); ?>";
            }, time);


            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        // reduce each second
        time = time - 1000;
        timeVal = (time / 1000) % 60;

        if (time >= 60) {
            // if time (seconds) are 60 or more show time as minutes
            unit = 'minutes';
            timeVal = Math.floor(timeVal / 60);
        }

        timeCount.innerHTML = timeVal + ' ' + unit;

    }, 1000);
}

// Show the modal window in last 2 minutes
function modalPopUp(time) {
    var remainingTime = time - 120000; // in my example is 240000 - 120000 (i.e. 4-2=2 mins)

    setTimeout(function() {

        // show modal
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        countDown(remainingTime);

    }, remainingTime);
}

function sessionExpire(time) {
    modalPopUp(time);
}
```

How can I do this work properly ?

Comment: The function `setInterval(callbackfunction, interval_in_ms)` expects a function as first parameter and not a calculation. The value it returns is the internal index of the interval you just created (and not the remaining time, as I think you are expecting it). You are also assigning the return value of the countDown function to the innerHTML of an element (which is undefined, as you are not actually returning anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with your `setInterval` syntax. **The parameters must be a function and time (in milliseconds)**, this function is executed for each interval. So change your logic to have a function as a parameter to your `setinterval` instead of the executable code.

Also I made some changes to just deal with a single function. Below is the snippet.

```js
// Show the modal window in last 2 minutes
function modalPopUp(time) {

  var remainingTime = time - 60000; // time is in miliseconds
  var timeCount = document.getElementById('time-remain');

  setTimeout(function() { // show the modal and display the remaining time to the user
   
    document.getElementById('modalID').style.display = 'block';
    setInterval(function(){         
      time= time - 1000; //reduce each second
      timeCount.innerHTML = (time/1000)%60;
    }, 1000);
  }, remainingTime);
}

modalPopUp(60000); //show modal.
```

```html
<div id="modalID" class="modal-content" style="display:none;">

  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <h2>Session timeout</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Your session is about to expire in <span id="time-remain"></span> and you will be logged out.</p>
    <p>
      <button class="btn blue" id="extend-session">Extend Session</button>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work fine! one additional question though ..when I click the `extend-session` button do I have to reset or clear the timer ?

Comment: Simply posting code is not that helpful. You should explain the OP's problem and how your code fixes it.

Comment: @Lykos you must assign the setInterval into a variable, then when you say extend you need to clear this interval.

Comment: You mean outside the function ?

Comment: @Lykos Yes it must be a global variable. So you can clear it from anywhere.

Comment: @RobG I have added what the OP's problem was. If you were the downvoter then if you think the answer now meets the standards you mentioned, then could you please remove the downvote.

Comment: I don't get, if I set `setInterval` to a variable how can I call it inside the `setTimeout` as you have it at the moment ? the `time` is accessible within the function

Comment: @Lykos it looks fine, and you can just have this initially `var interval;`  no need to assign a setInterval there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I didn't understand you.. could you explain more detail ?

Comment: @Lykos your code looks fine, But I dont think `var interval = setInterval(countDown(time), 1000);` here you require to assign the setInterval at this point as you will anyways overwrite it in the modalPopUp function. you can just do `var interval`

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work properly.. I have set the default time to 4 minutes, so the remaining time (i.e the time suppose to show on the message) should be 2 mins.. The window pops up in 2 minutes, as expected, however the countdown shows 59 secs, 58 secs, 57 secs ... so basically it doesn't show anything higher than a minute I did an update to the code to review

Answer (score 3):

The `setInterval` needs a callback function as first parameter:
`setInterval(function, interval in MS)`.

What you can try is:

- create a var holding the time untill session expires (`var secondsRemaining`)
- create a interval on 1000MS (1 second)
- in the interval callback, decrease the `secondsRemaining` by 1
- display the value of `secondsRemaining` in the span `#time-remain`

To make it more fancy and to your example, you can check whether to display `seconds remaining` or `minutes remaining` in the interval callback.

If `secondsRemaining` is higher than 60, you have `secondsRemaining / 60` minutes left.

In this example I used an interval of 100MS so you don't need to wait for minutes :)

https://jsfiddle.net/upkmg80r/2/